# $y'=K(y-a)(y-b) ; a,b,k\in \mathbb{R}$ Differential equation , how to decipher it?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$y'=K(y-a)(y-b) ; a,b,K\in \mathbb{R}$

a) Discuss the solutions of this Differential Equation

b) Discuss special solutions to the initial value conditions: $$u(0) < a , a< u(0) < b , b < u(0) $$

How can we solve this DE? I tried to guess a solution, but impossible to find a solution for me. Any technique which will help to give solution?

Answer (score 1):

That equation is separable:
$$
\int_{y_0}^y \frac{d u}{(u - a) (u - b)} = K \int_{x_0}^x d v
$$
where $y(x_0) = y_0$